# Problem with vertical alignmentof in table's environment "Tabu"

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabu

I need your help for this problem. Since a year ago, I'm using LaTeX for wirite a math handbook. From them until now, I've had a few problems but with this forum i have solve them. But now, I can't solve my lastest problem.

Recently, I bought a new computer and I reinstalled the lastest MiKTeX full installation and TexMaker. And when I added new code and I've compiled for my handbook, I obtained the next unpleasant result.

[image: The Result]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/grDAo.jpg

The code compilated are the following:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabu}{cX[m]}
$\mathbf{C}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{2n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\cdots&a_{nn}\\
\end{pmatrix}$&La dimensión de una matriz cuadrada es, por tanto, $n\times n$. 
Sin embargo, es mucho más usual decir que una matriz cuadrada \textbf{es de orden $n$}.
Por ejemplo, la matriz $\bf C$ es de orden $n$ (${\bf C}\in\mathbb{M}_{\,n\times n\,}$)
y la matriz $\bf D$ es de orden $4$ (${\bf D}\in\mathbb{M}_{\,4\times 4\,}$).
Dentro de este tipo de matrices cabe destacar dos elementos
\underline{exclusivos de las matrices cuadradas}: las \textbf{diagonales}.\\
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
```

As you can see, the text and the mathematical environment (the matrix) are not aligned and not centered, too. Which is what I want to achieve.

Also, this problem happens to me when I changed the computer: with my old notebook, the matrix and the text are perfectly aligned. The result was similar to the following:

[image: The Correct Result]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoQ8t.jpg

This I have achieved with the following code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{cm{\linewidth}}
$\mathbf{C}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{2n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\cdots&a_{nn}\\
\end{pmatrix}$&La dimensión de una matriz cuadrada es, por tanto, $n\times n$. 
Sin embargo, es mucho más usual decir que una matriz cuadrada \textbf{es de orden $n$}.
Por ejemplo, la matriz $\bf C$ es de orden $n$ (${\bf C}\in\mathbb{M}_{\,n\times n\,}$)
y la matriz $\bf D$ es de orden $4$ (${\bf D}\in\mathbb{M}_{\,4\times 4\,}$).
Dentro de este tipo de matrices cabe destacar dos elementos
\underline{exclusivos de las matrices cuadradas}: las \textbf{diagonales}.\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But the text overflows from the page. Is there any order, command or package to adjust the m type column to the end the page and avoid the overflow?

Thanks!
And sorry for my horrific english!

Comment: Where are the results?

Comment: Sorry! I cant upload the peictures. I'm modifying the post. Wait a moment, please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would not use `tabu` ... after recent changes in the package `array` is has one "bug" more: columns of the type `m` doesn't work anymore as expected.

better is used `tabularx:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{ \linewidth}{@{}
                            >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X
                            >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X
                              @{}
                              }
\[
\mathbf{C}=\begin{pmatrix}
            a_{11}  & a_{12}    &\cdots & a_{1n}\\
            a_{21}  & a_{22}    &\cdots & a_{2n}\\
            \vdots  & \vdots    &\ddots & \vdots\\
            a_{n1}  & a_{n2}    &\cdots & a_{nn}\\
            \end{pmatrix}
\]
    & La dimensión de una matriz cuadrada es, por tanto, $n\times n$.
Sin embargo, es mucho más usual decir que una matriz cuadrada \textbf{es de orden $n$}.
Por ejemplo, la matriz $\mathbf{C}$ es de orden $n$ ($\mathbf{C}\in\mathbb{M}_{\,n\times n\,}$)
y la matriz $\mathbf{D}$ es de orden $4$ ($\mathbf{D}\in\mathbb{M}_{\,4\times 4\,}$).
Dentro de este tipo de matrices cabe destacar dos elementos
\underline{exclusivos de las matrices cuadradas}: las \textbf{diagonales}.\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

Comment: The problem is the package _array_: it has been updated and it has completely changed my layout. Someone knows where I can obtain the old version of _array_ pakcage? The original code it was less cumbersome. But, thank you very much @Zarko for your solution! I will definitely choose your code.

Comment: @DavidGordo98, yes, this is problem. about his has been recently discusion here. search `tabu`  tags. as i remember you need to load `array` with option containing date of old `array`. since i mostly discourage people to use non maintained packages, i don't remember more :-(.

Comment: Yes, I've found the array-2016-10-06 package. But... I have a lot of compilation errors, i don't know why. :-(

Comment: @DavidGordo98, it seems that you should change all your `tabu` tables to `tabularx` or `ltablex` ones :-). i worth to send a letter with ask to package author if he is willing to make (just this) fix for the package. it is worth to try.

Comment: Oh! Good idea! Thank you! But, finally, when the package _array-2016-10-6_ AND new package _multicol-2017-04-11_, everything works like before.

Comment: And, @Zarko!!! Your comments have solved my problem and also, they have made me learn more LaTeX (still, hahaha). Thanks to you, this experience has been totally rewarding. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: Just for the record, v.2.10 of tabu (currently not yet on CTAN but here: https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu) seems to fix the tabu problem with `m` columns.